# How to use angle in geom_label?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am not sure how to use the aes `angle` in `geom_label`. I thought this code below would rotate the labels by 45, but it doesn't.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars[1:4,]) +
  geom_label(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec, label=disp), angle = 45)
```

Comment: This problem is discussed here: [Suggestion: implement "angle" as in geom_text](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/16)

Comment: @pogibas note that the link you posted deals with `ggrepel::geom_text_repel()`, not with `ggplot2::geom_label()`. So even though that issue is closed successfully, `ggplot2::geom_label()` still ignores `angle`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This does not work for `geom_label` but for `geom_text`:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars[1:4,]) +
  geom_text(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec, label=disp), angle = 45)
```

From `?geom_text`

> Currently geom_label does not support the `rot` parameter and is considerably slower than `geom_text`.

`rot` obviously refers to rotation and seems to be a deprecated parameter for angle.

Answer (score 5):

geom_text does not produce a label. You can use `ggtext::geom_richtext`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(data = mtcars[1:4,]) +
  geom_richtext(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec, label=disp), angle = 45)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>