# How to group in ggplot geom_bar R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am failing miserably trying to get my head around grouping in ggplot geom_bar.

I have a mock data frame structure, although the real data frame is significantly larger:

```
df<-data.frame(id=1:12,
    count=c(12,5,33,6,43,12,8,56,14,43,36,32),
    name=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","D"),
    stringsAsFactors=F)
```

using either the mock or in this case the real data frame, I get a plot like

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=id,y=count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

This plots everything in the correct order (as laid out in the data frame), however, along the x-axis, rather than the numeric *id* values, I would like to use the *name* as a group: "A" for the first three values, "B" six, "C" for the next two and "D" for the final value - or the proper names in the case of the full dataset.

I have a feeling this should be quite easy providing my dataframe is formatted is correct. Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your desired output is.  Will the values of `id` on the x axis be replaced by those in `name`?  Or should each `name` group be lumped together?  Or something else?

Comment: The values with identical names should be lumped together and labeled on the x axis. It just so happens that I have a (perhaps redundant) id column in there which is 1:nrow(df).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the labels in the `scale_x_discrete` function.

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(id=1:12,
               count=c(12,5,33,6,43,12,8,56,14,43,36,32),
               name=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","D"),
               stringsAsFactors=F)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(id), y = count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "name", labels = df$name)
```

[image]

If you only want one label per group, you can do the following to keep the label at the first bar of each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(name2 = ifelse(row_number() > 1, "", name)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(id), y = count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "name", labels = df2$name2) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or use `facet_grid`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(id), y = count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "id") +
  facet_grid(. ~ name, space = 'free_x', scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Almost what I need. I would like just for one label of A beneath both As, one label of B beneath the 6 Bs, else when I come to use my read dataset it is going to look very messy.

Comment: the facet_grid option is really nice!

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of the facets, as well.  If `id` isn't needed for labels, you could put the strips on the bottom with `switch = "x"` and then remove the axis ticks/text with theme elements.  Playing around with the spacing between panels might also be useful via `panel.spacing`.

Comment: Thank. I've gone for the none facet_grid option (your second plot) as I have far too many data points to make for a readable plot.

Comment: Having said that, how do I rotate the text now on running on the x axis? Not sure how to do this with theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()). Thanks.

Comment: take a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921805/how-to-use-angle-in-geom-label

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thank for your nice comment. I like your answer a lot as well and have upvoted your answer. Also, thanks for providing the post showing how to rotate the x-axis label for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it, we compute separately positions of letters, and separators for clarity, and we use `scale_x_continuous` / `breaks` / `labels` to plot them

```
l <- rle(df$name)$lengths
letter_pos <- cumsum(c(0,head(l,-1))) + l/2 + .5
sep_pos <- cumsum(l) + .5

ggplot(df, aes(x=id,y=count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(letter_pos, sep_pos),
                     labels = c(unique(df$name),rep("|",length(letter_pos))))
```

[image]