# Can't insert the writings inside the multiple barplot on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to show "Text" into my bars column, but I can't use "position_stack" in conjunction with "position_dodge" (which is crucial for me).
By the way, if I try to put the fill = "white" option in geom_text, the text changes position: no longer dodged (however, this wouldn't be a problem if only I understand how to insert the text into the bars).
Below the R code where I create the variables and make the graph.
Thanks in advance for the reply.

```
## Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpp)

options(scipen = 999) 

## Data creation
mese = c("Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic", "Gen", "Feb", "Mar")
Turnover = c(6279564,8527493,10673649,12318004,15441024,12294253,14020388,13403097,10610501)
Profitto = c(967507,1064425,1578481,468067,4001093,1971060,2371386,2200384,2441256)
Commissioni = c(480840,707767,903418,884598,1790805,1151400,1247108,1206451,1136362)

MG = cbind(mese, Turnover, Profitto, Commissioni)
MG = as.data.frame(MG)  

MG$Turnover = as.numeric(MG$Turnover)
MG$Profitto = as.numeric(MG$Profitto)
MG$Commissioni = as.numeric(MG$Commissioni)

ProfittoPct = round(100*Profitto/Turnover, 2)
ProfittoPct = paste0(ProfittoPct, "%")

CommissioniPct = round(100*Commissioni/Turnover, 2)
CommissioniPct = paste0(CommissioniPct, "%")


Text = c(paste0(format(Turnover, big.mark = "'"), " €"),
         ProfittoPct,
         CommissioniPct)
  
MG$mese = factor(MG$mese, levels = c("Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic", "Gen", "Feb", "Mar"))

## Plot
MG %>%
  gather("Type", "Value", -mese) %>%
    ggplot(aes(mese, Value, fill = Type)) +
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", col = 1) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16000000, 1000000))+
      theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())+
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
      geom_label(aes(mese, label = Text), position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = 0)+
      xlab("Mese")+
      ylab("€")
```

Comment: welcome to this forum. 1) Instead of creating the data here, it might be more concise to post the exact output of `dput(MG %>%
  gather("Type", "Value", -mese))` 2) More important - not quite sure what your desired look would be. Would you care making a sketch and posting? Its enough to show one exemplary group

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but if it's just about placing the text inside the bars, I think you're almost there. Just a bit of change in the geom_label layer. I've changed it to geom_text because vanilla geom_label doesn't allow text rotation. For this you could use `ggtext::geom_richtext` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67875680/7941188)). Or you can probably make some nice use of the {geomtextpath} geometries.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geomtextpath)

## your MG creation ...

## take it from here
MG %>%
  gather("Type", "Value", -mese) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mese, Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", col = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 16000000, 1000000))+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
            ## change y position and vjust and add angle
  geom_text(aes(mese, y = Value/2, label = Text), position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
             vjust = 0.5, angle = 90)+
  xlab("Mese")+
  ylab("€")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It's perfect!!
Thank you so much for the help! :')