# Alter angle of labels on Bar graph using ggplot 2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, visualization

Created a Bar Graph where each bar has a percentage label affixed. I'd like to change the angle of the text to make it easier to read. Months are aligned along the x axis and the sum of transacyions for each month are aligned along y, with a user type separating each month into two separate bars. the labels on the bars themselves are a separate percentage field to help clarify the proportion of each user type contained in the month.

```r
Chart_2022 <- Breakdown_2022 %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Month, 
    y = monthly_transactions, fill = Rider_Class)) + geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = prop), position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
        vjust = -0.25) + scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(suffix = "k", 
    scale = 0.001))
#> Error in Breakdown_2022 %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Month, y = monthly_transactions, : could not find function "%>%"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I've looked in the syntax of geom_text() and theme() and i can't seem to find the right statement to adjust it. I've also looked in geom_label to attempt more clarity but the labels are too crowded to work. I've also looked into changing the size but can't find the right adjustment.

UPDATE: Adjusting the element angle in theme() resulted in other elements being affected, but not the labels on the bars themselves

the code used was:

theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 45))

[image of bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGq1d.png)

Comment: unfortunately no, the theme changes the angles on text along the axes, but not the labels on the bars themselves

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Then just use the `angle` argument in `geom_text()`  instead. [How to use angle in geom_label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921805/how-to-use-angle-in-geom-label)

Comment: Thank you. sorry for the repeat question. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction